# How to use custom annotation processor with Maven 2?

Tags: java, maven-2, annotations, maven-plugin, annotation-processing

In our enterprise application we are seeking a dynamic way to collect data from our Java classes. We created a custom annotation interface (`@interface`) with a `name` property. We would like to collect the value of this property from all annotated classes.

I managed to create an `AnnotationProcessorFactory` and an `AnnotationProcessor` for the custom annotation. Since we are using Maven 2, I added the following to the plugins in the `pom.xml` of the main project.

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-alpha-5</version>
      <configuration>
        <factory>our.company.api.component.lister.ComponentAnnotationProcessFactory</factory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

This resides in the main project which has several sub-projects. The factory and the custom processor are in one of these sub-projects. The custom annotations are scattered through all of the sub-projects that is why I put the plugin in the `pom.xml` of the main project.

The problem is when I issue the `mvn apt:process` command I got a warning about the annotations without processors and our custom annotation is among them. I assume this means that the plugin cannot find the factory class.

What should I do so the plugin could find the factory and the processor file?

**EDIT:**

The project hierarchy is very simple:

```
main_project
|-sub_project1
|...
|-sub_projectn
```

The plugin is in the `pom.xml` of the `main_project`. Just assume that the factory and processor are in `sub_project1` and the custom annotations are in `sub_project2`, `sub_project3`, ..., `sub_projectn`

Comment: What does your project hierarchy look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things to check:

1. Make sure that the `main_project` (or the plugin) [depends on the project](http://mojo.codehaus.org/apt-maven-plugin/examples/configuring-a-factory.html) which contains your `ComponentAnnotationProcessFactory`.
2. The `<factory>` configuration tag of the Apt Maven Plugin did not work for me but the plugin finds the factory class if its fully qualified name is in the `META-INF/services/com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory` file. (See the [documentation of apt for the details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html).)

A better approach is using the [annotation processing features of JDK 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html) (instead of the Maven Apt Plugin) since it does not require the `com.sun` package and the `tools.jar` from the `lib` folder of the JDK.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>

                <annotationProcessors>
                    <annotationProcessor>
                        com.example.annotationprocessor.Processor
                    </annotationProcessor>
                </annotationProcessors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Further references:

- [Annotation Processing Tool](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue167.html) in the The Java Specialists' Newsletter
- [What is the default annotation processors discovery process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11685498/843804)