# What is the default annotation processors discovery process?

Tags: java, maven-2, annotations, annotation-processing, maven-compiler-plugin

The [documentation of Maven Compiler plugin mentions the following](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#annotationProcessors):

> **annotationProcessors:**
>
> Names of annotation processors to run. Only applies to JDK 1.6+ If not 
>   set, the default annotation processors discovery process applies.

What is the *default annotation processors discovery process* here? Is there any other way to set up annotation processors than this configuration tag?

I've found that the [Getting Started with the Annotation Processing Tool (apt)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/apt/GettingStarted.html) documentation mentions a *default discovery procedure*, but it works with *factory classes* not processors and unfortunately it uses the `tools.jar` and `com.sun` packages from the JDK. Is this the default annotation processors discovery process?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The default way to make an annotation processor available to the compiler is to register it in a file in `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor`. The file can contain a number of processors: each the fully-qualified class name on its own line, with a newline at the end. The compiler will default to using processors found in this way if none are specified.

Comment: To be specific, it's just a [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) for `javax.annotation.processing.Processor`