# Pattern for processing custom Java annotations

Tags: java, design-patterns, annotations, annotation-processing

I have read a lot of tutorials about Java annotations lately and I like the idea of creating a custom one. Most articles cover the very basic idea and fairly simple implementations. I'm missing a proper pattern to *process* my annotation, though.

Lets say I have a custom annotation `@Foobar` to initialize fields. I need to pass **all** classes that use this annotation to my processor, let's call it `FoobarProcessor`:

```
public class AnnotatedClass {
  @Foobar
  private String test = "";

  static {
    FoobarProcessor.process(AnnotatedClass.class);
  }
}
```

Is there any approach to overcome this drawback? Is there any *single point* that all classes pass, where I can easily apply my annotation processor?

Answer (score 2):

A common pattern to process annotations or any language elements is the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Java even includes a standard API for to this: [SimpleElementVisitor7](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.compiler/share/classes/javax/lang/model/util/SimpleElementVisitor7.java)

If you need an example implementation of a processor using the pattern, take a look at the code of the [PrintingProcessor](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/processing/PrintingProcessor.java). The processor traverses all kind of elements it find and prints some information. It's used for javac's non-standard Xprint option (you can try it in your command line: `javac -Xprint java.lang.Object`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the processor in a META-INF file. This answer should give you more info:

[What is the default annotation processors discovery process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685498/what-is-the-default-annotation-processors-discovery-process)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process your annotation at Runtime, you need to scan the classes from information of the classLoader, this answer give more information about it:
[How do I read all classes from a Java package in the classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456930/how-do-i-read-all-classes-from-a-java-package-in-the-classpath)