# a jar contains text file

Tags: java, jar

So I have a jar file (`eclipselink-jpa-modelgen_2.1.1.v20100817-r8050.jar`) which contains `META-INF/services` directory which just contains a file named `javax.annotation.processing.Processor` (*that's it, nothing else*) The funny thing is, its not an executable. It is a just text file which contains this data:

> org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor

I also have `eclipselink.jar` which have above class file

My question is, is there any chance that `eclipselink-jpa-modelgen_2.1.1.v20100817-r8050.jar` is being used by application during runtime.
Or in simple words is it safe to delete that jar?

Comment: This is used for auto-discovery of annotation processors. I am not 100% sure but this should be compile-time only, so probably not required in the runtime.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685498/what-is-the-default-annotation-processors-discovery-process

Comment: https://www.developer.com/java/article.php/3848881/Service-Provider-Interface-Creating-Extensible-Java-Applications.htm

Comment: Standard SPI descriptor.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html.