# Annotation processor discovery process since Java 9

Tags: java, java-9, annotation-processing, java-10, java-11

I am building a Java 11 application with Maven.

I have a modularized annotation processor as a dependency and I want it to be discovered and run by javac, but I cannot make it work as expected. (Or maybe my expectations are wrong?)

I have `provides Processor with ...` in my `module-info` file, and don't have any files in `META-INF/services` in processor jar, that is new way `ServiceLoader` works, right? This processor jar is passed to javac in `--module-path` property, but no processors were executed.

I tried specifying this dependency in `<annotationProcessorPaths>` for compiler plugin, but it uses `-processorpath` propery, which is an old way! This dependency doesn't have `META-INF/services`, so no processors were detected and run.

When I manually specified this in `<compilerArgs>`:

```
--processor-module-path=${settings.localRepository}/<path_to_my_jar>
```

...then processor was found and executed!

So, javac has a "default annotation processor discovery process" and here is an old answer about it: [What is the default annotation processors discovery process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685498/what-is-the-default-annotation-processors-discovery-process)

But this discovery process isn't working for me since Java 9.

Despite my processor jar is in modulepath, no processors gets found until I manually specify processor jar with `--processor-module-path`.

So there are 2 problems:

1. Javac doesn't find an annotation processor in modulepath
2. Maven compiler plugin doesn't have any way to specify modularized annotation processors except raw `<compilerArgs>`

Am I missing something?

Comment: --processor-module-path is the right option to use, you shouldn't expect javac to locate annotation processors on the module path specified to javac with --module-path.

Comment: @AlanBateman May I ask why the inconsistency? If `--processor-path` is not specified then javac will locate annotation processors on the `--class-path`, why is it different for `--processor-module-path` and `--module-path`?