# Run annotation processor of a maven module in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, annotations

I have a Maven Module with an annotation processor that works perfectly well during compilation from the command line. It registers the annotation processor with `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor`

The default annotation discovery process is to use `javax.annotation.processing.Processor`:
[What is the default annotation processors discovery process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685498/what-is-the-default-annotation-processors-discovery-process)

In intelliJ IDEA I have set the following option:

> Obtain processors from project classpath: leave this option enabled if
> you use a custom annotation processor as part of your project, or if
> the processor is stored in a .jar file attached to all the
> corresponding modules as a library.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotation-processors-support.html

The annotation processor checks several conditions for an annotated method, including that the method is static.

I can annotate a method with the annotation for which the annotation processor is registered, but it seems that the annotation processor is not invoked in IntelliJ IDEA: I can remove `static` from the method declaration and I do not see any error in the IDE.

I found some (possibly outdated) explanation: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206232249-Annotation-Processor-defined-in-Jar-not-automatically-detected

The questions:

- Does IntelliJ automatically detect `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor`?
- What does this exactly mean `Obtain processors from project classpath`? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotation-processors-support.html
- How can I enable IntelliJ IDEA to detect the annotation processor registered in `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` of some maven module ?

Note: when I write "I do not see any error in the IDE" this means that I do not see errors in the editor, e.g. similar to the case when `@Override` is underlined for a method that does not actually override a method from the superclass.

When I build the module from the IDE, I do see an error. However, I would like to see errors during the coding (similar to `@Override`), not during the compilation.

Comment: Is the annotation processor in the same module as the code to process? Aside from that, since you have a `module-info.java`, you might want to try `provides javax.annotation.processing.Processor with com.yourdomain.YourProcessor;`.

Comment: Also you might want to set the [`<annotationProcessorPath>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#annotationProcessorPaths) in the `maven-compiler-plugin`. Also, does the annotation processor run when compiling with Maven?

Comment: As I posted in the question, `works perfectly well during compilation from the command line`,so I do not need anything else. According to the maven docs, `<annotationProcessorPath>` is used when the processor is not registered

Comment: I didn't downvote (at least I'm saying that) but here are possible reasons: They could have downvoted because they felt like it (people can vote how they like, see [Tim Post losing his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/525172)); You asked multiple questions at once. Stack Overflow requires each question to focus on a single questions (although I think all your three questions might actually be asking the same thing, whether or not you know it). Someone also close-voted your question for that reason so that's _probably_ why they downvoted (but it can also be someone else!)

Comment: Your downvoter probably doesn't read your comments so I gave you reasons why they might have downvoted (people don't need to provide reasons for downvoting).

Answer (score 0):

IDEA has in-build Maven support through the [Run Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-maven.html) and [Maven Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-projects-tool-window.html) - if you use those options your Project should be build exactly as you'd be using Maven.

IDEA also has its' own Build System ([Build Menu](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#compile_module)) that is somewhat compatible with Maven, which is also capable of working with `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor`.

`Obtain processors from project classpath` option does exactly what it says on the tin - IDEA will be looking for the Annotation Processor in the list of JARs supplied in your Project's classpath.

For Annotation Processors to work as intended:

- They must be added to
  `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor`.
- [Profiles](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotation-processors-support.html#annotation_processing) should be configured in such a way, that would allow
  IDEA to find them (and hand them over to the compiler).

Comment: Thanks, but I noted in my question that the project compiles exactly as I expect, quote `I would like to see errors during the coding (similar to @Override), not during the compilation.`